# CourseMill API: Getting a Response from my Request

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to connect to the CourseMill API and cannot get a response from the server. I can't find any walkthroughs online and believe it has something to do with my Authentication URL. When I try and add `verify = False`, it gives me a 404 Error.

I am trying to do things like updating course assignments, adding exemptions, etc. from Excel via Python as well as customized reporting into dashboards.

Documentation:
https://www.trivantis.com/help/CourseMill/7.5/en/ProgGuide/Content/21.html

Home Page URL for CourseMill Admin: https://learningcenter.company.com/admint/home.html?switchRoleReq=1

```
import requests

# API endpoint for authentication
auth_url = "https://learningcenter.company.com/cm-server/api/v1/auth"


# Authentication credentials
username = "user123"
password = "password"

# Data to be sent in the POST request
data = {
    "username": username,
    "password": password
}

# Sending the POST request to authenticate
response = requests.post(auth_url, json=data, verify=False)

# Check if the request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
    response_data = response.json()
    
    # Extracting the token from the response data
    token = response_data["data"]["token"]
    
    print("Authentication successful.")
    print("Token:", token)
else:
    print("Authentication failed. Status code:", response.status_code)
```

Errors:

````
InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'learningcenter.adm.com'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  warnings.warn(
Authentication failed. Status code: 404```
````

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1042, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 414, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 449, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 493, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 513, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 1071, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 1342, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:997)```
````